# TopToolStripPanel won't show in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I'm currently trying to create an image previewer in my program, which I'm doing by creating a UserControl. All seems to be working great, except that I now would like to move some of my buttons to the top of the UserControl.

I have done this by creating a ToolStrip and adding two buttons and a combobox. My problem is, that the new ToolStrip (toolStrip1 - see Document Outline pic.) won't show when I run my program.  I have tried settings `toolStrip1.visible = true` and using the `.BringToFront()` method, but none of these options seems to work.

Can someone help me solve this irritating problem?

P.S. toolStrip2 is showing just fine in BottomToolStripPanel.

[image: ImagePreviewer]

Picture 1: My Document Outline

[image]

Picture 2: My Image Previewer Design. The top bar is toolStrip1 which I'm currently not able to see when I run my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've quickly duplicated your layout, and it worked without a problem here.

Do you not by any chance set the "TopToolStripPanelVisible" property on the "toolStripContainer" to 'False' programatically?